# Redirect after Log out

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller, routes

I have an application i Laravel 6 where I want to change the blade.template to another template file than welcome.blade.php when the user logs out.
The purpose is that I would like to use welcome.blade.php as the landingspage.

Anyone with an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Laravel's default auth system, all you need to do is override the logout method in your LoginController (app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController).

```php
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect(route);
}
```

You can return anything from that method that can be returned from any other controller so you can either have it redirect somewhere, render a view, call another controller action etc.